# Using ACLs to block traffic destined for the switch

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, acl

There is a layer 3 switch which is responsible for inter-vlan routing. One VLAN (10, network: 172.16.10.0/24) cannot be accessed from any other VLANs (for management purposes). In order to do that I used the following ACL

```
access-list 1 permit 172.16.10.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 1 deny any

interface vlan 10
ip access-group 1 out
```

This blocks any traffic with source IP address outside VLAN 10 from exiting out the VLAN 10 SVI interface.

I chose to block the traffic when exiting the VLAN 10 SVI interface instead of blocking the traffic when entering all the other VLAN SVI interfaces because new VLANs can be added later, which means setting the same ACL for the new VLANs as well.

The problem is that the layer 3 switch has a management interface (172.16.10.1) which any VLANs can access, because the traffic will enter through the SVI interface corresponding to the source VLAN and it will remain in the switch. It will not get a chance to be filtered by the ACL which resides at the exit of the VLAN 10 SVI.

Is there a solution for filtering traffic destined to this interface residing on the switch without putting ACLs on inbound traffic for every other VLAN SVI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to restrict management access to the switch, you need to apply the ACL to the VTY interfaces:

```
ip access-list standard MY-ACL
permit ip 172.16.10.0 0.0.0.255

line vty 0 15
access-class MY-ACL in
```

Comment: So this can be used without the ACL that I wrote. In real life, which option would be chosen, this one or the one suggested by @Ron Maupin?

Comment: If your intent was just  to restrict management access to this switch, I think this is simpler.  If you have other requirements (it wan't too clear from your question), we need to look at other options.

Comment: Depending on the switch model and IOS version, you might consider VRF to isolate management access.

Comment: It was mainly a theoretical problem. I was told I had to isolate the management VLAN from the others, without any more details. I tried the solution in the post, then I realized the problem. I don't know almost anything about VRF, I will read about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You must put the ACL before the target from the perspective of traffic routing. Your problem is that the ACL is after one of the targets. Also, such an outbound ACL will actually route traffic that is destined to be dropped. If you place inbound ACLs, then the traffic will be dropped before resources are used to route the traffic.

You could have a single ACL that is used by the other interfaces, but, as you pointed out, you will need to add this ACL to any future networks you may add that should not access that network.

Comment: So there is no way to filter packets which are already inside the "routing engine"? The only solution is to put inbound ACLs on every other SVI?

Comment: That would be the correct way to do it. ACLs are evaluated as traffic attempts to pass through the interface. Your problem is that the traffic to that interface is going to the interface, not through the interface. As I wrote, you don't need multiple ACLs for the other interfaces; you can create a single ACL for all the other interfaces.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was referring to. Ok, thank you!

Comment: Also, you must consider the case of someone attempting to manage the switch through any of the other interfaces on the switch.

Comment: Are you referring to the situation when someone tries to connect to 172.16.20.1 (from inside VLAN 20), while this IP is assigned to the SVI of VLAN 20 on the switch? So, afterall, the solution proposed by @Ron Trunk should be the correct one?

Comment: What @RonTrunk suggested will protect the switch from someone trying to use the VTY lines to access the switch itself, but there are also other ways to try to attack the switch or other devices on the management network. It really depends from what, specifically, you are trying to protect.

Comment: At the moment I do not know anything about other management options. But thank you for now.

Comment: OK. As you will notice, using the VTY ACL as outlined doesn't prevent other things, For example, uses will still be able to ping that interface.

Comment: The layer 3 switch also serves as a DHCP server so DHCP requests from end users still have to pass.

Comment: I understand that other traffic must reach the switch, but my point is that those services and traffic don't need to reach the management SVI to work correctly. It really depends on what you want to do. Your original question seemed to want to block everything from that interface, but the VTY ACL doesn't do that. That's all I'm trying to warn you about.

Comment: So the same inbound ACL on all other SVI interfaces dropping traffic with destination VLAN10 should deny any type of traffic to the VLAN 10 SVI interface as well as all other devices on VLAN 10. But as you mentioned, being a layer 3 switch it has management interfaces on all SVIs. I know that authentication can be used. From @Ron Trunk's answer now I know that ACLs can be used for VTYs as well. Is there a way to block traffic going to those interfaces (despite the fact that in order to be routed it will reach them)?

Comment: If you want to block all traffic for a target, you must put the ACL before the target, at the interface(s) through which traffic will pass. Your original outbound ACL will block all traffic outbound from the SVI to any devices on that network, and the VTY ACL will block traffic through the VTY lines (usually telnet or SSH) to the switch SVI, but nothing else. It really depends on what you are trying to do. If you want to block all access to that interface, then you must use inbound ACLs. You cannot block all access to the other SVIs because those are the gateway addresses, so can be attacked.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. Finally, I think I will use both the solutions in these answers. I will filter traffic with destination VLAN10 as soon as it hits any of the other SVI interfaces, using an inbound ACL. And I will restrict the management access (from the other VLANS) using both the VTY ACL and authentication.